# How to plot bivariate function involving modulus and floor functions?

Tags: graphing-functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I need to plot:

- $\displaystyle\large|||x|-2|-1|+|||y|-2|-1|=1$
- $\displaystyle\large\left\lfloor\frac{|3x+4y|}{5}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{|4x-3y|}{5}\right\rfloor=3$

either for finding area of some region or the length of the wire, if used to make the graph(maybe the line integral.) Only consider the plotting of these graphs:

[image] and [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first :

The graph is symmetry both about $x$-axis and $y$-axis. So, we only need to consider the case when $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$. Then, note that 
$$|||a|-2|-1|=\begin{cases}-a+1&\text{if $0\le a\lt 1$}\\a-1&\text{if $1\le a\lt 2$}\\-a+3&\text{if $2\le a\lt 3$}\\a-3&\text{if $a\ge 3$}\end{cases}$$

For the second :

Since 
$$\frac{|3x+4y|}{5}\ge 0\ \ \text{and}\ \ \frac{|4x-3y|}{5}\ge 0,$$
each term of the left-hand-side is **a non-negative integer**.

Hence, we have only four cases as the followings :

(1) 
$$\left\lfloor\frac{|3x+4y|}{5}\right\rfloor=0\ \ \text{and}\ \ \left\lfloor\frac{|4x-3y|}{5}\right\rfloor=3.$$

(2) 
$$\left\lfloor\frac{|3x+4y|}{5}\right\rfloor=1\ \ \text{and}\ \ \left\lfloor\frac{|4x-3y|}{5}\right\rfloor=2.$$

(3) 
$$\left\lfloor\frac{|3x+4y|}{5}\right\rfloor=2\ \ \text{and}\ \ \left\lfloor\frac{|4x-3y|}{5}\right\rfloor=1.$$

(4)
$$\left\lfloor\frac{|3x+4y|}{5}\right\rfloor=3\ \ \text{and}\ \ \left\lfloor\frac{|4x-3y|}{5}\right\rfloor=0.$$

Comment: that's just easy when you're considering $f(a)=|||a|-2|-1|$ but maybe it's  that's not the case.Or consider explaining how can we plot sum of $f(x)+f(y)=1$. Assume I'm clear with plotting of $f(x)=1$

Comment: oops second one was just too easy :(

Comment: For the case when $0\le x\lt 1,0\le y\lt 1$, we have $(-x+1)+(-y+1)=1$, which is a line. For the other cases, you'll get lines which you should know how to plot them.

Comment: oh so you consider a prduct set of 4 cases each for x and y, thanks

Comment: @Aditya: Yes, exactly. You are welcome.